# Azure table data load performance

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 2 tables with 1 TB of data each in an Azure SQL database; using Azure Data Factory copy activity, we are loading the data into an on-premise SQL Server into 2 tables. It's a direct load, no transformations exists. The pipeline has been executing for more than 6 hours now. When I check the CPU utilization, it is at 80%.

I tried run in parallel. I have used copy activity and run but no use.

1. How can I reduce my pipeline execution time in Azure Data Factory?
2. Is there any alternate way to load data from Azure SQL database to an on-premise SQL Server table with less cost?

Comment: 1.  Increase the number of parallel copy activities to improve data movement throughput. You can achieve this by increasing the "degree of copy parallelism" setting in Azure Data Factory. However, setting this number too high can sometimes hurt performance, so it's recommended to set it as (DIU or number of Self-hosted IR nodes) * (2 to 4). (Source:  [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#parallel-copy-from-sql-database))

Comment: Increase the "Data Integration Units (DIU)" setting in Azure Data Factory to utilize more computing resources. This is applicable when using Azure Integration Runtime to copy data. (Source:  [Copy data from Amazon RDS for SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-rds-for-sql-server#parallel-copy-from-sql-database))

Comment: Monitor the CPU and memory usage on the self-hosted IR machine, and be ready to scale up the machine or scale out to multiple machines when you see that the CPU and memory are fully used. (Source:  [Use Azure Data Factory to migrate data from an on-premises Netezza server to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-migration-guidance-netezza-azure-sqldw#implement-best-practices))

Comment: Regarding an alternate way to load data from Azure SQL database to an on-premise SQL Server table with less cost, you can consider using Azure Data Factory's "Copy data from Azure Blob storage to SQL Server" template. This template uses PolyBase to load data from Azure Blob storage to SQL Server,which can be more cost-effective than using Azure Data Factory to directly load data from Azure SQL database to SQL Server. (Source:  [Copy data from Azure Blob to Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-dot-net#run-the-code))